# Forbidden when I'm trying to edit one page

Tags: editor

I have a page on my website with the slug let's say "blablabla". 
Several days ago, I've made by mistake a folder on server with the same name "blablabla". After that, when I try to modify and save my page having the slug "blablabla", I receive as error a white page with only a word " Forbidden". All the others pages can be edited with no problems. Of course, I've read here a similar answer (that the problem is the folder with the same name as page)  and I deleted the folder . To my surprise, this didn't solve the problem, I still receive same error and I cannot edit the page (and is one of my important pages on website...) . I suspect that there is a cache on server or in Wordpress which still remember that folder name. Do you know a method to eliminate it ? Or can be other problem which does not allow me to edit that page ? (so the folder was only a coincidence ?) Thank you very very much for your answer.

Comment: Hi, first of all enable the WP_DEBUG, and also php error. maybe there is a kind of error

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, it was caused by ModSecurity module in CPanel. For unknown reasons, it blocks the edit of that WordPress page (only that page). I disabled ModSecurity and works now. I'll contact my hosting company to see what's wrong (I cannot make any configuration in my Cpanel for ModSecurity)